# Excel changes appearance of an export list after clicking on the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wrote a makro for an Excel export of a third party tool.

### Content:

- Column A lists all the check-in times
- Column B lists all the check-out times
- Lines are just all the days from a certain period

### Target:

Check if the check-in time of the following day is later than the check-out time of the current day. So:
`=$A1>$B2`  and so on.

### Problem:

Lets assume the check-in time is always 8 am and the check-out time is always 6 pm. The times of the export are displayed like `8:00`, `18:00`, .. . In that case the output is always displayed wrong as `true` (I assume because the comparison is working unit by unit). If I click in the check-in field, the appearance changes to `08:00`and the output of the formula changes to `false`.

Do you have any idea, why? Format of the cell remains untouched ([hh]:mm) for both.

Comment: Your times are text, not actual times (formatted numbers). Try `=--$A1>--$B2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your times are text, not times (which are just formatted *numbers*).

Use the double unary `--` to coerce the text to a number:

```
=--$A1>--$B2
```